# Can't add anything to JFrame without catching an error

Tags: java, swing, jframe, addition, illegalargumentexception

For some reason, every time I call `frame.add(new class);` I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (class)
```

. To fix this error, I simply have to change my `frame.add(new class);` to `frame.add(frame, new class);` but this throws the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself
```

I don't know how to satisfy both Exceptions without throwing the other off, hence satisfy **both**.
Any help is appreciated as I don't use JFrames much.

Comment: `class` does not extend from `Component`...?

Comment: @MadProgrammer *facepalm*

Comment: Welcome to the forest, look out for the trees ;)

Comment: :) Nice job there